# How to add keys to the Symfony configs and solve the "unrecognized option" issue?

Tags: symfony, configuration, yaml, config, symfony-3.4

I'm working on a Symfony `3.4.6` app, that has a lot of YAML configuration files in the `[project root]/config/packages`. I added a key to one of them (let's say `xyz.yaml`):

```
xyz:
  ...
  foo:
    bar: 123
    buz: 567
```

Now I'm getting an error:

```
In ArrayNode.php line 319:
Unrecognized option "foo" under "xyz"
```

I took a look into the `ArrayNode.php#319`. Well, the thing is clear: arbitrary / additional keys are not allowed. There seems to be something like a whitelist. But where is it defined / how to extend it (add the new keys to it)?

**How to solve the "unrecognized option" issue by adding keys to Symfony configs?**

Comment: you cannot just add keys to configs. they have to be defined by the bundle first. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @craigh Thank you for the comment. Yes, I got it, but where can I add my new key to the bundle's "config whitelist"? It's a custom bundle (not a vendor one), so I may change this. What I'm trying to achieve, is to add some functionality to a custom bundle, and this functionality should be configurable.

Comment: Look in the XyzBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration class and adjust accordingly.  Then update the extension class to do something with the new values. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/configuration.html#processing-the-configs-array  Be sure to get a good night's rest before tackling this.  The Configuration class can really mess with your mind.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html is what you want to read. And it isn't as bad as @Cerad says, imo.